# Read data from QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

I have some problems with read Data from socket( use QDaTaStream for it). The problem is unknown protocol of data that receive my client from server. How can I read this data at least partially?
This task without of code example from my side, because I can read, but i receive unreadable data.

Comment: Without knowing the protocol is impossible. :)

Comment: so I can't just read all bytes from stream and convert info to string with hope to see some valid words?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Does the server send data using 1 unknown protocol which you do not know how to decode? Or, does the server send data in 1 of n possible protocols and you do not know which one it uses? In the first case ... reverse engineering. (I would start with a hex dump (with ASCIIs for what is printable) but this can become tedious depending on how complex the protocol is.) In the second case, this reminds me how image loaders detect file format from contents. For this, some first bytes are read and then checked against "magic codes" of the known image file formats.